# Getting Checkbox Value in ASP.NET MVC Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app. The model for my form looks like the following:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

In my form, I have the following HTML.

```
<label class="checkbox pull-left">
   <input type="checkbox" id="IsActive" name="IsActive" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsActive field is required.">
   <i></i>Active/Deactive
   <input name="IsActive" type="hidden">
</label>
```

When I post the form, the IsActive value in the model is always false. However, the Name property in the model has a value. I've tested this by setting a breakpoint in the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(ViewModel model)
{
    // model.IsActive always is false
}
```

Why isn't the Checkbox value getting set?

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not setting the `value` attribute in either the checkbox or its associated hidden input so no value is posted and the value of your property is its default value (`false`). It needs to be

```
<label class="checkbox pull-left">
    <input type="checkbox" id="IsActive" name="IsActive" value="true" ....>
    <i></i>Active/Deactive
    <input name="IsActive" type="hidden" value="false">
</label>
```

Side note: Is there any reason you're not using `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive)` to generate the correct html?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set value attr of the check box to fetch the value .

> data-val is different and not used as value attr in either HTML or MVC

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use razor and `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive)`.

Comment: It is usually better to elaborate on the answer in first attempt itself or the OP would ask you for the same later...